# Running script bad interpreter: Permission denied

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, sh

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/sugarcrm-6.5.15/apps/sugarcrm/htdocs# chmod +x install_all_modules.sh
root@ubuntu:/opt/sugarcrm-6.5.15/apps/sugarcrm/htdocs# ./install_all_modules.sh

for dir in 'libeo/*/'
 ./install_module.php libeo/Agenda/
 ./install_all_modules.sh: ./install_module.php: /usr/bin/php: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

What im doing wrong when running the script

Answer (score 0):

generally, the error indicates that the script requires an interpreter that is not present or doesn't have the rights to process the file.

as you have already done a chmod, my guess would be that php-cli, the php command line interpreter, is missing. 
In a standard setup, PHP is installed as a module of the webserver, so that it gets only invoked in the server context. To use php on the command line you need to have the aforementioned php-cli package.

on ubuntu (sudo) `apt-get install php5-cli` should do the job.